# Batch of notifications takes ~10 seconds

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm performing batches of 50 notifications requests to facebook graph api using POSTMAN and cURL according to the docs: [batch-api-docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/)

Entire batch completion takes from 7 to 10 seconds with 46 success and 4 errors which is very slow.

Single success request(without batch I mean) takes like 1 second so I expected batch will take similar time but it's not. Does anybody know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

A batch request only reduces the number of HTTP requests you are making. It does not affect anything else that is going on in the background.

Sending a notification to a user *and* getting a success/error response will simply take a certain amount of time. And multiplying that amount by 1 or by 50 is just going to result in different numbers.

Comment: in addition to that, 50 calls in 10 seconds is still a lot faster than 50 calls in 50 seconds ;)

Comment: Faster but in 5 times instead of 50 which is not what you expect and if you have to send a lot of notifications you're expecting reasonable throughput increase with batch. It would have been great to be mentioned in Docs that this batch is more sequential than parallel.